# How to resolve Unexpected 'select' error in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Code:

```
Delete from Table1
Where(A,B,C)
IN
(Select A,B,C From Table2);
```

If there is matched record then it should delete the records from Table1.
When I executed the above code, I got the error like unexpected select and unexpected From error

Comment: I created 2 simple tables (table1 and table2 with a,b,c olumns), and then I tried to execute the exact query (copied from your message). I could delete the the records from table1 without getting any error. Could you share the exact error message, and the query?

Comment: Error: SQl compilation error:Syntax error line 10 at position 1 unexpected 'select'

Comment: As I see the query is only 1 line, but the error says "line 10". If you are using web interface, could you mark the query and run it? Or could you put a semi column (;) before the query so it will be separated from the previous ones?

Comment: I am running this query through data stage Job. Please consider the query in 1 line only. I have split into multiple lines. There is no other query

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to do something like this:

```
delete from table1 using table2 
where 
  table1.a = table2.a and
  table1.b = table2.b and
  table1.c = table2.c
```